# Cassandra nodetool Status show me error . i want to know the status of my cassandra node

Tags: configuration, cassandra

[image: ConnectException: Connection refused]

Cassandra Nodetool Status show me error when i run Nodetool status command. I want to know the Status of my Cassandra node.

Comment: please insert image...

Comment: From that "connection refused" error message did you check cassandra is currently running? Can you connect to it using cqlsh ?

Comment: Tail the system.log and make sure that the Cassandra process hasn't exited due to an error.

Comment: either c* isnt running or its bound to a different interface than 127.0.0.1.  `netstat -an | grep 7199` will show what its bound to. Are you using ccm or something that uses a different port for jmx by chance?

Comment: @JKVS one more thing, cassandra also not running every time when i check  the status of cassandra output like this appears.                                               Cassandra Status (Exited).

Comment: @Aaron but it is exited . how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: (as Aaron said above) You need to look in the system.log from the bottom up for any errors. That will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error when Cassandra is not running, check whether Cassandra is running or not. If running you may need to check the hostname configuration.

To configure the hostname Visit https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/error-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-17199-connection-refused-cassandra-solved/

Answer (score 1):

I kept having this error, and the status of cassandra was on actived(exited). I fixed it increasing the RAM of the virtual machine(i think 2GB would be enough)